# How to apply selection sort on a csv file data which is read into a struct based on a specific column?

Tags: c++, sorting, selection-sort

[image: enter code here]
I am reading an excel .csv file data to a struct. I am supposed to apply selection sort algorithm to this data on the basis of number of employees and then saving this sorted data into a new .csv file. I have wriiten this code but its not working.

```cpp
vector<Details> results;
    ifstream inputFile ("C:/Users/Mubashra Zaman/Downloads/organizations-100.csv");
    Details swimmer;
    string line;
    
    while (!inputFile.eof() && getline(inputFile, line, '|'))
    {
        cout << line << "\t";
        stringstream ss(line);
        Details swimmer;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1e4; i++)
        {
            if (ss >> swimmer.index >> swimmer.organization_Id >> 
            swimmer.name >> swimmer.website >> swimmer.country >> 
            swimmer.description>>swimmer.founded>>swimmer.industry
            >>swimmer.number_of_employees)
            {
                results.push_back(swimmer);
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Selection sort Function:

```
void selectionSort(Details data[], int size)
{
    for (int startscan = 0; startscan < (size - 1); startscan++) 
    {
        int minindex = startscan;
        string minvalue = data[startscan].number_of_employees;

        for (int index = startscan + 1; index < size; index++)
            if (data[index].number_of_employees < minvalue)
                minvalue = data[minindex = index].number_of_employees;

        Details temp = data[minindex];
        data[minindex] = data[startscan];
        data[startscan] = temp;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Can you be bit more specific than, "it's not working"?

Comment: Any particular reason for not using [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Comment: It seems that you do not read the CSV file correctly. Because you just read until the first '|' from the file. Can you please kindly add the text-file structure, maybe one line as an example and the definition of your struct "Details"?

Comment: `struct Details
{
 int index;
    string organization_Id;
    string name;
    string website;
    string country;
    string description;
    string founded;
    string industry;
    string number_of_employees;
    
};`

Comment: @MubMalik:  Code is best placed into your question rather than comments.  I suggest you edit your question and then delete your comment.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your input data, paste as text into your question.  FYI, applications other than Excel can generate CSV files.

Comment: @AdrianMole I think the selection sort function is not accessing the values correctly..It is giving error

Comment: *'...It is giving error'* -- Please be specific on the errors you are getting. On the side, you are storing `number_of_employees` as strings right now, so any sorting applied on them will be done lexicographically(likely not what you wanted).